# App Script works in editor but permissions denied when running from sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I'm trying to make a script that syncs group membership to whatever emails are in this google sheet. I put the main body of my script in the `onEdit` function so it runs every time any cell is changed. I wrote (copy and pasted) a function that gets all the members of a group (called `getGroupMembership`) and I ran this function from the editor **and went through the authorization flow.** Now when I click "Run" with `getGroupMembership` it runs without errors and gets the membership.

The problem is, that when I have the spreadsheet open and I make an edit, I get a permission error in the logs (`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.members.list failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.`)

By the way, I need this to work so that if anyone who has access to the sheet edits it, it updates the membership. This script will also eventually be hooked up to a google form so when the form updates the sheet the script should update the groups.

```js
function getGroupMembership(groupKey) {
  var rows = [];
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
      page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupKey,
      {
        maxResults: 500,
        pageToken: pageToken,
      });
      var members = page.members
      if (members)
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
        {
            var member = members[i];
            if(member.role == "OWNER") {
              // Owners aren't going to be listed in the spreadsheet
              continue;
            }
            rows.push(member.email);
        }
      }
      pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return rows;
}
```

Comment: Try using an installable onEdit and don't forget to not use onEdit as the name.  The onEdit is a simple trigger an cannot perform operations that require permission.